# Swipeable horizontal scrolling in div on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

So I have a page where I have a main image frame, and below it I have thumbnails.
When the user clicks on a thumbnail, the main image frame changes the image to the image shown in the clicked thumbnail. Like a carousel. **See the image below.**

Now, my problem is, if the user will add 20 thumbnails, I don't wanna show all. I want the thumbnails to always show just the 3 and be swipeable on mobile, so you can scroll horizontally and browse the thumbnails.

So let's say my code is:

```
<div class="main-image-frame">
   <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-container">
  <div class="thumbnail>
    <img src="tnail.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail>
    <img src="tnail.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail>
    <img src="tnail.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail>
    <img src="tnail.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail>
    <img src="tnail.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail>
    <img src="tnail.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it horizontally scrollable and swipeable in mobile? I guess a combination of CSS and js but I have no idea how to start

[image: scrollable thumbnails]

Answer (score 2):

No need to use JavaScript. It can be done using CSS.

Set the container to a fixed width, and give it two important properties:

```
overflow-x:scroll;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Then for each thumbnail, have the following:

```
display:inline-block;
```

```css
.container {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:calc(100% - 40px);
  margin:10px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  padding:10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
 .thumbnail {
  background-color:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
 }
 .thumbnail img {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.bobbyberberyan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HTML5CSS3Logos.svg"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```